# How to customize headers and footers in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, headers

I just has a header to my Google Sheets like this:
[image]

How do I now change the size or color of these texts?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time the feature to customize headers and footers doesn't include a way to set a custom formatting (font, color, size, effects like bold, italics, etc.).

One alternative is to use rows to hold the header / footer text and use the cell formatting or in cell text formatting to customize the "headers" and "footers"

Related Q&A: [Adding a header and footer to a Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/50091/88163)

Related Help Article: [Add headers, footers & page numbers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/86629?hl=en)

Comment: Dear Rubén
Thank you very much for your tip!

I was able to use the first rows for the header, freezing them and using the printing options.

But how can I do the same for the footer?

Comment: @CeuMelo AFAIK it's not possible to freeze non-consecutive rows and I never tried to use row freezing for footers, so I don't know (at this time).